# Compute planar geometry, vectorial math, and 3D equations in SWIFT/iOS

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, math, geometry

Working on a project here which will require some awesome math resourcefulness. I'm looking to make calculations to verify things like: if a point is within a volume / shape (in this case: rectangles or trapezoids) in a given 3D space, how to generate a class or some kind of object to hold the "equation" parameters of such a volume. 
Also looking at ways to perform dot product computations in Swift.

Would there be a well-known library out there? 
The only things I can seem to find are for SceneKit and graphics rendering Frameworks.. this project is purely computational, as in there is no UI output of the calculated results.
Any resources or examples are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For those who mind stumble upon this kind of issue,

I eventually found the built-in framework for making this kind of math possible.

Called Accelerate, it's even optimized per-OS.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate

Best of luck!